# print multi-page gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a multi-page gridview, and i want to print all the pages.

here is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="verifiedsum" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="false" style="margin-left:100px;width:500px">
    <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="RegNumber" DataField="RegNumber" /></Columns>
    <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname" /></Columns>
    <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Firstname" DataField="Givenname" /></Columns>
    <PagerSettings Visible="false" />
</asp:GridView>
<a style="margin-left:100px">Page: <asp:DropDownList id="PageSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageSelect_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></a>
```

I am thinking generate a word file to export the table, but call word application from server side is complicated too (i think).

Does anyone know how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did

```
            int verifiedamount = 0;

            string line = "";
            List<CVerifiedList> VerifiedList = yourList
            for (int i = 0; i < VerifiedList.Count; i++)
                if (VerifiedList[i].Verified == "Verified")
                    verifiedamount++;
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("", "text/plain");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "tests.csv");


            foreach (CVerifiedList verified in VerifiedList)
            {
                line = verified.RegNumber.ToString() + ", " + verified.Givenname + ", " + verified.Surname + ", " + verified.Verified+",\""+verified.Reason+"\"\n";
                Response.Write(line);
            }
            Response.Write("Number of verified:" + ", " + verifiedamount + "\n");
            Response.Write("Total amount:" + ", " + VerifiedList.Count);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to print any server control alike GridView, DataGrid, Panel, TextBox etc.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/printing-in-Asp-Net/

You can use this to print a GridView with paging enabled:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20903/Printing-a-GridView-with-Paging